# QGIS - Create single contour line at specific height from DEM

Tags: qgis, dem, contour

I wish to create a single contour line of height 4.54 m from a DEM layer. Any idea how I may do this please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a couple of examples are:

1. QGIS main menu `Raster | Extraction | Contour`
2. Processing Toolobox `SAGA | Vector <-> raster | Contour lines` (or `SAGA | Vector to raster | Contour lines`)

---

(1) QGIS `Contour`

After setting your input file and output filename, turn the bottom window into "edit mode" by clicking on the pencil mark. Then add `-fl 4.54` in the command line. Click on [OK] button to run.

(2) SAGA `Contour lines`

Just give your 4.54 (m) to both Minimum and Maximum Contour Value.